# How to use the bibliography tab in Verbtex?

Tags: bibliographies, verbtex

I am working on a project of article with Verbtex on Android for which I haven't added the references yet. There is a bibliography tab, but I can't figure out how to use it. I would like to use sentences like "see [1]" in my document to refer to the first reference, etc. How can I do that as simply as possible as I want to focus on math and not on computer science issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process with VerbTeX is the same as with 'regular' LaTeX. You need to collect all your references in a bibliography file, which in VerbTeX is accessible in the <kbd>Bibliography</kbd> tab. Each reference has an entry with fields for author, title, etc. See for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Standard_templates for an overview of entry types and fields. Then, in your main document, you should add the `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` commands - they are provided as comments in the standard VerbTeX template so you can just uncomment those. The `\bibliographystyle` command controls the bibliography style, if you want numbers then you should use the `plain` style. Then, to actually cite a reference, use the `\cite` command with as argument the key of the reference that you want to cite.

Some screenshots, of the <kbd>Bibliography</kbd> tab, the main document, and the result:

[image: bibliography file]
[image: document file]
[image: result]

Comment: Thank you so much! You save my evening.